# Why aren't my SQLite queries executing in my Qt Application

Tags: qt, sqlite

I have a Qt application which utilizes SQLite as a database. In the Qt Creator environment all my queries are executing perfectly and everything is fine but when i run the executable in my project folder no query is executing and i receive an error "No query,unable to fetch row". My database is open so i don't know what the issue is. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Maybe your sqlite plugin does not load when your run your application from its location?

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding absolute path to the database for testing? Qtcreator might use different work directory than shell.

Comment: Thanks the absolute path suggestion worked, but what if i want the application to work on a different computer with no such path? Is there a way to make the path relative?

Answer (score 0):

You should place your SQLite database file alongside your executable. Also:

On Windows:

- Place QtSql4.dll alonside your executable
- place qsqlite4.dll in a folder named "sqldrivers" beside your
  executable

These dll files are in your installed Qt Directory in bin folder.

On Linux:

- Place libQtSql.so.4 alonside your executable
- place libqsqlite.so in a folder named "sqldrivers" beside your
  executable

These so files are in your installed Qt Directory in lib folder or in director "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu".